# How to update data in one component when changes are made in another component in angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have total 3 components namely filterComponent,tableViewComponent and Homecomponet.
filterComponent - contain filter option for filtering data in tableViewComponent.filter option like date-range etc..
tableViewComponent - shows table format of data.
homecomponent- is base component in which other 2 components are shown.

What I wanted is when I change date range in  filterComponent(I make api call here and I get the data here) it must update the data in tablecomponent(I have pagination also here). but here 2 different component I don't know how to achieve that. before this I included all the data range(like filter)option and table view in the home component .Now I am breaking into two component .I am using angular material

//tableComponent

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8  responsive-table">

      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.NODE_ID}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="CMTS Name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> CMTS Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.CMTS_NAME}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.STATUS}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Homes On Node">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Homes On Node </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.TOTAL_ADDR_CNT}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-paginator [length]="totalPages" [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageIndex]="pageIndex" [pageSizeOptions]="[10]"
    (page)="nextPage($event)">
        </mat-paginator>
    </table>
</div>
```

//filtercomponent

```
<div class="row" id="filter-panel">
    <form [formGroup]="angForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="col-1">
            <mat-form-field class="range-datepicker">
            <input [(value)]="date" matInput placeholder="Choose a date" [satDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="date"
        (dateInput)="onDatePickerValueChange()">
            <sat-datepicker #picker [rangeMode]="true">
            </sat-datepicker>
            <sat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></sat-datepicker-toggle>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <button mat-flat-button color="primary" class="search-btn">Search</button>


    </form>
</div>
```

//filtercomponent.ts

```
onSubmit() {
    this.spinner.show();

    this.pageIndex = 0;
    this.ApiServiceObj.getMarkerDataForTableView(this.startdate, this.enddate, this.regionOption, this.pageIndex, 10).subscribe((res) =>         {
     this.generateMapRespose(res['results']);

     this.totalPages = res['totalPages'];

     this.spinner.hide();

    });
  }
```

//homecomponent

```
  <div>
      <app-filter> </app-filter>
     <app-table></app-table>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

The best way (from my opinion) would be to work with input and output. So I would add an event to your filter component to emit an event when the filter changed.
e.g.

```
export class FilterComponent {
    @Output() filterChanged = new EventEmitter();
    ...
    onSubmit() {
        this.spinner.show();

        this.pageIndex = 0;
        this.ApiServiceObj.getMarkerDataForTableView(this.startdate, this.enddate, this.regionOption, this.pageIndex, 10)
            .subscribe((res) => {
                this.generateMapRespose(res['results']);

                this.totalPages = res['totalPages'];

                // TO NOTE that you need to emit the data to the parent component
                this.filterChanged.emit(res);

                this.spinner.hide();
            });
    }
}
```

From the code you posted above it looks like, that you are fetching the data in the filter component, I'd personally rather just emit the filter options to the parent component, so that your HomeComponent decide where to fetch the data from. Additionally you need to add an Input property to your table component. You can do this, similar to:

```
export class TableComponent {
  @Input() data: any;
}
```

With this approach you have a very clear seperation of concerns and also a very clear data flow. Your filter component is responsible for gathering the filter informations, your homeComponent uses those to gather the data properly and passes this to the tableComponent which takes care of proper rendering.

This is from my point of view the most straight forward way of handling this problem. There are several different mechanism how to handle the situation. You can read about it in detail here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Another approach would be using the Service with a Subject Pattern.
You define a service which has a property for the data. Your FilterComponent would emit values over this subject and your Table component would subscribe to that.
Such a Subject could look like this:

```
export class DataService {
  private dataSub = new Subject();

  getData$(){
    return this.dataSub.asObservable();
  }

  setData(data:any) {
    this.dataSub.next(data);
  }
}
```

I personally think that you don't need the roundtrip over the additional needed subject. Also it introduces the complexity of RxJS, which you might want to skip for now.

All in all I would go for the dataflow via input & output. Hope that helps!